# How to add padding to pandas.TimeGrouper

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Here is the data:

```
date
2016-03-23    hiit
2016-03-30    hiit
2016-04-20    hiit
2016-08-24    hiit
2016-09-04    hiit
2016-10-19    hiit
2016-10-24    hiit
2016-11-07    hiit
2016-11-24    hiit
2016-12-01    hiit
2016-12-04    hiit
2016-12-15    hiit
```

When I group them by month using

`df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('MS')).count()`

Reality:

```
date
2016-03-01    2
2016-04-01    1
2016-05-01    0
2016-06-01    0
2016-07-01    0
2016-08-01    1
2016-09-01    1
2016-10-01    2
2016-11-01    2
2016-12-01    3
```

Desired (data starts from `2016-01-01`)

```
date
2016-01-01    2
2016-02-01    2
2016-03-01    2
2016-04-01    1
2016-05-01    0
2016-06-01    0
2016-07-01    0
2016-08-01    1
2016-09-01    1
2016-10-01    2
2016-11-01    2
2016-12-01    3
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Your data doesn't have `January` or `February` so why do you expect it to give you counts for those two months?

Answer (score 3):

Reindex it:

```
r = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('MS')).count()
r.reindex(pd.date_range('2016-1-1', periods=12, freq='MS'), method='bfill')
Out[413]: 
            data
2016-01-01     2
2016-02-01     2
2016-03-01     2
2016-04-01     1
2016-05-01     0
2016-06-01     0
2016-07-01     0
2016-08-01     1
2016-09-01     1
2016-10-01     2
2016-11-01     2
2016-12-01     3
```